# How to remove ros-groovy-simulator-gazebo without removing all of ROS?

Tags: gazebo-1.9, groovy

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm completely new to gazebo and find it difficult to understand which version I should be using in combination with ROS groovy.

[Here](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Install/Gazebo_and_ROS#Using_Gazebo_on_ROS_Groovy) it sounds like I should stick to the ROS package ros-groovy-simulator-gazebo, but [this link](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/1.9/install) gives clear instructions on how to use standalone gazebo 1.9 with ROS groovy.
So for the moment I expect that I should be able to use version 1.9. Is this correct?

However, when trying to install gazebo_ros as described [here](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/Installing_gazebo_ros_Packages), it says I should remove the old version of gazebo as per

```
sudo apt-get remove ros-groovy-simulator-gazebo
```

but apt-get tells me it's going to uninstall all of ROS if I continue:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
 ros-groovy-desktop-full ros-groovy-erratic-robot ros-groovy-pr2-simulator ros-groovy-simulator-gazebo
```

Can somebody plaese point me in the right direction which version of gazebo I should install and how exactly I should go about it?

I'm aware of the same question being asked [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/46367/remove-gazebo-but-keeping-the-rest-of-ros/), but the accepted answer isn't actually an answer to the problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5556/how-to-remove-ros-groovy-simulator-gazebo-without-removing-all-of-ros?/) by [SimonHarst](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/649/simonharst/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-02-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Desktop-full includes simulator-gazebo, so removing simulator-gazebo does trigger the removal of all of those packages. If you first do something like:

`sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-desktop`

And then remove gazebo, you should be able to continue with the instructions.

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) with karma: 319 on 2014-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SimonHarst](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/649/simonharst/) on 2014-02-27**:
Thank you very much, that worked indeed. For the record, a lot of other packages were marked as obsolete, too, like e.g. ros-groovy-rqt-rviz and were therefore uninstalled. After removal of these packages and install of ros-groovy-desktop everything works fine, though. The rest of the gazebo 1.9 and gazebo-ros installation worked like a charm. Thanks again!